# How to customize installshield error message?

Tags: installshield-2012

We have quickpatch project for our minor product update. It is based on existing MSI package.
If this patch is run on a machine which does not have the required product installed, following installshield error is displayed:
1628: Failed to complete installation.

This may sound bit odd but is there any way to customize this message using quickpatch or using msi project from BaseImage folder?

Any help on this will be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately 1628 is a fairly generic Windows Installer error, and we don't offer a way to configure its message. I would probably advise just documenting this, and living with the limitation. People aren't generally too surprised that they need the base product in order to patch it.

If you really need a way to control your message, you could look into delivering your .msp using an Advanced UI or a Suite/Advanced UI project. You can create a condition that detects the base package, and use it either as part of the eligibility for the patch package or use it negated as an exit condition (in general information). You can specify a custom message for the exit condition.